# Why is the stored procedure resulting all the values which contains either coll_cd or div_cd

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a stored procedure with optional parameters as shown below.

Stored procedure:

```
declare @sr_div_cd varchar(10) = null,
        @coll_cd varchar(10) = null,
        @coll_div varchar(10) = null,  
        @flag int = null
AS
    if (@flag = 1 or (@sr_div_cd is not null or @coll_cd is not null or @coll_div is not null))
       select 
           vc.SR_DIV_CD, vc.COLL_CD,
           vc.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM, vc.COLL_DIV_LAST_TERM,
           pg.MAJOR_CD, pg.DEG_CD,
           pg.PROG_STRT_TERM, pg.PROG_LAST_TERM
       from  
           SR0VCT vc 
       join
           SR0PGT pg on vc.COLL_CD = pg.COLL_CD 
                     and vc.SR_DIV_CD = pg.SR_DIV_CD 
                     and vc.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM = pg.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM 
       where
           (vc.SR_DIV_CD = @sr_div_cd AND @sr_div_cd IS NOT NULL) 
           or
           (vc.COLL_CD = @coll_cd AND @coll_cd IS NOT NULL) 
           or
           (vc.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM =@coll_div and @coll_div  IS NOT NULL) 
    else 
       select 
           vc.SR_DIV_CD, vc.COLL_CD,
           vc.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM, vc.COLL_DIV_LAST_TERM,
           pg.MAJOR_CD, pg.DEG_CD, pg.PROG_STRT_TERM, pg.PROG_LAST_TERM
       from  
           SR0VCT vc 
       join 
           SR0PGT pg on vc.COLL_CD = pg.COLL_CD 
                     and vc.SR_DIV_CD = pg.SR_DIV_CD 
                     and vc.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM = pg.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM
```

In the above query when I give the values for any one of the i/p parameter, it is resulting the exact output, but when values for any two of them or three of them are given this stored procedure is resulting all the values which contains any one of the value which is common to particular field

ex: when I pass @sr_div_cd = 'AA' this sp resulting all the rows where @sr_div_cd = 'AA'

But when I give @sr_div_cd = 'AA' and coll_div = '95' , this sp resulting all the rows which has 'aa'in div_cd or '95f' in coll_div.but i am trying to result rows which satisfies =the condition @sr_div_cd = 'AA' and coll_div = '95'.

Can anyone please help me ?

Comment: Is this MySQL or SQL Server? They are not the same thing. The reason you are getting OR is because you put OR in between the filters.

Comment: this is in sql server

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting OR is because you put OR in between your conditions. You have your ORs and ANDs mixed up in your code. You are probably looking for this

```
WHERE  (vc.SR_DIV_CD = @sr_div_cd OR @sr_div_cd IS NULL) AND
   (vc.COLL_CD = @coll_cd OR @coll_cd IS NULL) AND
   (vc.COLL_DIV_STRT_TERM = @coll_div OR @coll_div IS NULL)
```